# Issue with nested Framework for Watchkit Extension

Tags: ios, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch, ios-frameworks

My Watchkit app does not work in production (TestFlight && rejected from AppStore).

I think the issue come from a nested framework. Here the architecture :

I've made a framework "ModelLayer" (Cocoa Touch Framework) with the app's model, so it can be shared across all targets. This framework use another third party framework (UICKeyChainStore.framework).
And the apple watch extension use "ModelLayer".

When debugging everything works fine. But when I uploaded the archive on iTunes connect I had an error saying that nested frameworks where not allowed. So I removed the copy file phase that I had in the Build Phase of "ModelLayer"'s target. It did not worked well as the app has been rejected...

I found some threads on internet that says that the copy file phase should have as Destination 'Shared Frameworks' and not 'Frameworks' (as I've done before). So I tried this, I've uploaded a pre-release of my app on itunes connect and tried the app with testflight. The app is now on my Apple Watch, but impossible to load the app. The loader stay on screen.

Did I miss something ? How can I use UICKeyChainStore.framework in my 'ModelLayer' framework ??

Thanks in advance !

[image: Build phases of my framework : ModelLayer]

[image: Apple Watch app result via test flight]

Comment: @rmp I've just find the solution, my problem was not link with a keychain problem as my app was working when debugging. But thanks for your tip ! I didn't know that there were an accessibility parameter for the keychain, and it solved me another bug that I had with my WatchKit app.

**I will post a response to my question tomorrow.**

Comment: Great, glad it was of some help and you got your app working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution.
The third party framework in my custom framework was not the problem. But It was my custom framework in the watch kit extension. So it's not possible to embed directly a framework in an extension. The framework should be embedded by the main app. And the extension will be able to use it.

### Add the framework to the main app target

In Build Phases Tab

[image]

### Use the framework in extension target

In General Tab

[image]

And in Build Settings Tab -> Linking
Add `@executable_path/../../Frameworks` to Runpath Search Paths

[image]

Comment: hey it didnt worked for me? when followed this steps i am getting framework not found error on app target

Comment: @muku I had this issue with watchOs 1.0, now on watchOs 2.0, the extension may run directly on Apple Watch. So it may cannot get frameworks from the Main App (on iPhone). I haven't switch from watchOs 1.0 to 2.0 for my project yet, so I'm not sur about that.

Comment: Please, can you explain in other way the last step? Linking Add @executable_path/../../Frameworks to Runpath. In my project this information already appears. Must I change it?